# Hide input password when typing (shell)

Tags: linux, csh

I want to hide the input password  like ****** when typed.
Here's the code i've created

```
set valid_password = $<
set password = '1234'

if ( password != valid_password) then
      echo 'please re-enter password'

else

if (password == valid_password) then
      echo 'password is correct'

end

exit
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow! Some tips for asking questions: (1) When you put code in your question, make sure to format it so others can read it easily. (2) Make sure to state what programming language you are using. This looks like bash to me so that is how I tagged it -- if you aren't actually using bash then sorry and please retag! (3) See the help center for more tips!

Comment: @ChrisBeck this is csh not bash

Comment: Ok thanks for your advice . I'm a newbee in programming and only self study.. it is use chs .. sorry for my mistake..

Comment: This is easy to do using the bash shell. If that's a viable alternative, read the documentation for the built-in `read` command. If you're stuck using csh, I feel obligated to show you this link: http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot

Comment: You can turn off echoing entirely with `stty -echo`. I don't think there's any non-trivial way to make it echo `*`.

Comment: You're missing `$` before all the variable names.

Comment: This is not related to what you're asking about, but this: `if ( password != valid_password) then` is comparing the literal strings `"password"` and `"valid_password"`. You need to write `if ($password != "valid_password")`

Comment: Thanks Keith Thompson.. :)

Answer (score 1):

If it is acceptable that you just don't get any password characters echoed (instead of *) then the following CSH will loop until the valid password is entered:

```
#!/bin/csh

set valid_password = '1234'
while (1)
  echo -n "Enter your password: "
  set password = $<
  if ("$password" == "$valid_password") break
  echo "Incorrect password!"
end
echo "Goody!"
```